# Converting Maven resources to gradle resources

Tags: maven, gradle, resources

We are moving from Maven to Gradle and I am stuck on the issue below. In our current pom.xml we have this:

```
<resources>
     <resource>
         <targetPath>deploy/config/directory1</targetPath>
         <directory>config/directory1</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
         <targetPath>deploy/config/directory2</targetPath>
         <directory>config/directory2</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
         <targetPath>deploy/scripts</targetPath>
         <directory>scripts</directory>
     </resource>
```

We have a unit test that does

```
getClass().getResource("/deploy/config/directory1/somefile.txt")
```

I do not want to change the pom.xml as that structure is needed for deployment reasons until we fully migrate to Gradle. I am trying to do the equivalent in gradle with not much success:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
         }
        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                "config/directory1",
                "config/directory2",
                "scripts",
 ]
 // output.resourcesDir = "$buildDir/deploy"
 }
}
```

A have a few issues with this:
1. The files in the config/directory1 and config/directory2 are copied to the root location of the resources folder. I would like to keep the structure the same so there would be a single config directory under the resources dir and then config dir would have directory1 and directory2.
2. I can set the output.resourcesDir as shown however that means I have to change my java code to

```
getClass().getResource("somefile.txt")
```

which is what I have to avoid.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this is:

```
processResources {
   from("scripts") {
      into("deploy/scripts")
   }
   from("config/directory1") {
      into("deploy/config/directory1")
   }
   // etc
}
```

Answer we from Sterling on the gradle forum here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/converting-maven-resources-to-gradle-resources/16447/2?u=domcc